# Checking for the convergence of a series with factorial at the numerator

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to check for the convergence of the series $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{a^n}$$ for $$a \in R$$ Now: If $$ a \geq 0 $$ I am pretty sure the series diverges since the $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{a^n} $$ goes to $\infty$. If $a<0$ I have an alternating sign series which, it seems to me, diverges as well (I fail to find a test which proves the opposite. The Leibniz, for instance, is not valid since the limit of the positive part goes also to infinity.
Am I on the right track? I also can not come up with an analytical argument for the limit going to infinty but I am just arguing that the factoria "grows faster".
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Let $N$ be large enough that $N \geq 2a$.  
Now $\frac{(N+k)!}{a^{N+k}} \geq 2^k \frac{N!}{a^N}$, which goes to $\infty$ with $k$.

Comment: If $\sum_n b_n$ converges, then $\lim_n b_n = 0$. This is always true, even when $b_n$ is alternating. Since $\frac{n!}{a^n}$ does not converge to $0$ for any value of $a$, neither does the series converge for any value of $a$.